# Capabilities YoctoProject SDK V1.8

Tags: yocto

I am trying to install the capabilities in my image of the yocto project with SDK V.1.8 for the T2080.
I already did it with the SDK V.2.0 for the development kit T2080RDB-PC and for them to work I had to enable the fields in the kernel:
Ext2 extended attributes
Ext2 Security Labels
In addition to saying that the 'libcap' should be installed in the .conf file. But with SDK V.1.8 I can not get the linux capabilities in my final system.

Searching for 'setcap' in the directory of SDK V1.8 and SDK V2.0 I have found that an executable is missing in SDK V1.8. I show this difference in the attached images. As you can see, an executable is missing in the SDK V1.8 of 'setcap' in the directory '... / rootfs / usr / sbin' I thought that maybe I did not have the capabilities with the SDK V1.8 and yes with SDK V2.0 is related to this.

[image: SDK V1.8]

[image: SDK V2.0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to install the capabilities in my system.

For this I had to activate the following kernel fields:
All 'system extended attibutes', the 'POSIX Access Control List' and the 'Security Labels' for system files.

I also had to activate the following security options:
'Different security models' and 'The securityfs filesystem'.

In addition to the configuration of the kernel I had to manually install the libraries 'attr-2.4.44' and 'libcap2_2.22' on my system